# How do I prove that a function decreases/increases on an interval?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I had to determine where the following function is increasing and where it's decreasing. I can figure those out, but how do I write it down with correct notation and how could I prove it?

$$ f:\mathbb{R}\to\ \mathbb{R} \qquad x\mapsto(x-3)^4 $$

I know that I can calculate the extremum/extrema by taking the second derivative:

$$ f''(x)=((x-3)^4)''=(4(x-3)^3)'=12(x-3)^2 $$

and taking finding its root(s):

$$
12(x-3)^2=0 \\
(x-3)^2=0 \\
x-3=0 \\
x=3
$$

I know of course, that $\mathit{f}$ has an extremum, more specifically a minimum at this point ($x=3$)

And I can see from it's graph and by substituting values that it decreases on $]-\infty,3[$ and increases on $]3,+\infty[$

But how do I write this down and prove it? I was thinking about using sequences to prove, maybe?

Comment: Out of interest, you could take what you "see from the graph" and see what you get by substituting in points $x=3 \pm \epsilon$, where $\epsilon >0, <0$ both sides of the root. You would then get $f(3 \pm \epsilon) = (\pm \epsilon)^4  = \epsilon^4$. Its an equivalent way effectively by transitioning the function. Then $f'(3 \pm \epsilon)=4\epsilon^3$ which is strictly $> 0$ for $\epsilon>0$ and $<0$ similarly

Comment: You need to take a step back and really understand what the 1st derivative represents; it's gives you the slope of the tangent in a certain point `x`, as a function of `x`. If you plug in a certain `x` into the 1st derivative and it returns `0`, it means the tangent is parallel to the `x` axis at this point. Likewise, positive value for a certain range of `x` values will mean the function is increasing. You got the result by accident, since what you had to do is find the roots of the *1st* derivative, not 2nd.

Comment: @Groo I realise that now, I was confused because before doing this problem, I've done one involving finding inflection points, which require finding the root(s) of the second derivative. _as an aside, in such a case, should I edit my original post? I am quite new to the site_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to solve the inequality $$f'(x)=4(x-3)^3\geq 0$$ or 
$$f'(x)=4(x-3)^3\le 0$$
thus your function is increasing if $$3\le x<+\infty$$ or decreasing if $$-\infty<x<3$$

Comment: You have given an unstrict inequality for the first half and a strict one for the second half, seemingly for no reason.

Answer (score 6):

You find the extremum by taking the first derivative, not the second.  You will still get $x=3$ in this case.  Then to show the function is increasing on $]+3,\infty[$, you just need to show the first derivative is positive on the interval.  So take the first derivative and show that.

Answer (score 4):

The big theorem connecting the derivative to monotonicity is:

> If $f'$ is positive on an open interval, then $f$ is increasing on that interval (in fact, the closure of that interval).  Likewise, if $f'$ is negative on an interval, then $f$ is decreasing on that interval.

In your case, the derivative is $f'(x) = 4(x-3)^3$.  This is negative on $-\infty < x < 3$ and positive on $3 < x < \infty$.  So $f$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,3]$ and increasing on $[3,\infty)$.